# Angular HTML5 mode with express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I know there are answers to this question, but they're not fully working for me. I'm using Angular 1.4 and Express 4. Express is handling API calls and Angular is supposed to be handling all HTML.

My express app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

require('./routes/api')(app);

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
// This covers serving up the index page
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/.tmp')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/app')));

app.all('*', function(req, res) { 
  res.redirect('/index.html'); 
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is angular app.js

```
angular
  .module('punyioApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/howitworks', {
        templateUrl: 'views/howitworks.html',
        controller: 'HowItWorksCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'howitworks'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

Now, if I go to http://localhost:3000/, I get the main Angular view, as expected. The problem is when I go to http://localhost:3000/howitworks, which redirects me to http://localhost:3000/index.html and does not show the 'howitworks' view. How do I fix the express router so that I can go to http://localhost:3000/howitworks ?

Comment: Why are you using `app.all(*...` and not simply `app.get('/', ....`?  Thanks.

Comment: My client is a separate project, essentially. The express app doesn't have a 'howitworks' endpoint. My Angular code understands it, though. I'm looking for how to send the unknown URL to Angular.

Comment: And if I can redirect to index.html, it seems like I should be able to send this to Angular somehow that works for Angular.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is simply redirecting every request to `index.html`, which isn't what you want. You do need that file, but since Angular handles the routing, you only want Express to send the file, no questions asked.

Basically, you shouldn't be using `redirect`, but `sendFile`:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) { 
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});
```

Also, as someone pointed out in the comments, you should use `get` and not `all`.

Comment: Add a specific route handler before this one: `app.get('/api/some', ...)` and then `app.get('/*', ...)`

Comment: That's it! Thanks @Pier-Luc

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau Why is it, that every time I try to implement this & I go to an url of mine, that I download that file instead of opening the page.
I also made a post about this but I can't seem to fix it with your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394053/html5angularjs-cannot-get-detail

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angularjs ui-router ,there is no need to use express,you can use node-static or just nginx ,and use grunt or gulp connect plugin  to dubug,I think it's better this way.

Comment: Express is handling the RESTful API and I want to be able to deploy everything on one server. It may be a touch weird, but I like the setup.

Answer (score 0):

In case of jade you can use:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
res.render('index.pug');
});
```