# Remove the /#/ from angular URL has any bad consequence?

Tags: angularjs, html, express, friendly-url

I have a mean app, i've setup angular to `html5Mode(true)` does it has any consequence?, also i would like to know how could i configure angular to be able to change from mode if the browser doesn't support it.

Here's my express conf:

```
/* main module entry point */
'use strict';

var Express = require('express');

var env = require('./src/server/components/env');

var app = module.exports = Express();

app.use( require( './src/server/modules/auth' ) );

app.use(Express.static(__dirname+'/src/client/'));

app.get('/*', function(require, response){
    response.sendfile(__dirname + '/src/client/index.html');
});

app.listen(env.port, function () {

    console.log('Listening to port ' + env.port);

});
```

And here's my angular module conf:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [
        /*
         * Shared modules
         */
        'app.layout',
        'app.core',
        /*
         * Feature areas
         */
        'app.users'
    ])

        .config(['$locationProvider', hashbagRemove]);


    function hashbagRemove($locationProvider){

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }

})();
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102815/how-to-delete-sign-in-angular-ui-router-urls (but the answer is in there)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular HTML5 mode with express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778324/angular-html5-mode-with-express)

Comment: @juanvan that's what i've tried but i get that error...

Comment: @AnidMonsur as i said i've already tried that..

Comment: You have not posted your express code, so I don't know what you've tried. Enabling html5mode in Angular is only half of the solution.

Comment: Hmmm, i didn't know that i had to do something at Express, what i've done is a simple Express setup @AnidMonsur

Comment: I found the answer there, thanks @AnidMonsur, should i delete the question? i would like to know about the impact of this