# ExpressJS - GET method returning different result

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

**Story:**
I created an ExpressJS  application with 2 GET methods. The first one is for rendering the index.html and another one for returning a JSON mock data.

**Problem:**
Opening the URL on browser that will ( expectedly ) return a JSON mock data, the app keeps on rendering my index.html.

**Dependencies:**
    "angular": "^1.5.8"
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.8"
    "angular-aria": "^1.5.8"
    "angular-material": "^1.1.3"
    "angular-messages": "^1.5.8"
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.5.8"
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.4.2"
    "ejs": "^2.5.6"
    "express": "^4.15.2"

**Code:**

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.engine(".html", require("ejs").__express);
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get("*", function(request, response) {
        response.render("index");
});

app.get(“/get-mock-data”, function(request, response) {
    var mockData = {
        “name” : “Michael Ardan”,
        “gender” : “M”,
        “birthday” : “2017-01-01”,
        “other_details” : “chubby”
    };
    response.send(mockData);
});

app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log("Listening on port " + port);
});
```

**my-angular-app.js**

```
angular.module(“TestApp” , [
    "ui.router",
    "ngMaterial"
])

.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    var homeState = {
        "name" : "home",
        "url" : "/home",
        "templateUrl" : "views/home.html"
    };

    var aboutState = {
        "name" : "about",
        "url" : "/about",
        "templateUrl" : "views/about.html"
        “controller” : “AboutController”
    };

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider.state(homeState);
    $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
});
```

**Other details:**
- I tried to change

```
app.get("*", function(request, response) {
        response.render("index");
});
```

to

```
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
        response.render("index");
});
```

while this works for me, I cannot access http://localhost:3000/about on browser directly. Instead, the server keeps on returning "Cannot get /about". I had to access the page from http://localhost:3000 and click About from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML5 mode with express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778324/angular-html5-mode-with-express)

Comment: While the question looks similar to the one you have posted, I still think this question is different with different accepted answer. As part of my 'Other Details', I tried the answer on the question you have mentioned and it didn't work. You may check my accepted answer to see how the answers differs from each other.

Comment: I noticed the order of routes too, but thought to myself: that shouldn't be an issue when you're calling `/about`, because it wont be caught by `/get-mock-data`. Maybe I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express will render the first route that matches your "query". You're putting the default/catch-all route **before** your mock data. Switch the order and everything will work just fine.

Do this:

```
app.get(“/get-mock-data”, function(request, response) {
    var mockData = {
        “name” : “Michael Ardan”,
        “gender” : “M”,
        “birthday” : “2017-01-01”,
        “other_details” : “chubby”
    };
    response.send(mockData);
});

app.get("*", function(request, response) {
        response.render("index");
});
```

Comment: Never thought that the answer will be as simple as this. Thanks @andrerpena

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I do not have enough knowledge to explain it directly, but your GET request should be addressed to index.html, not Express app. Everything's about Html5Mode.

There's same case and also solution for your problem: [How to use AngularJS routes with Express (Node.js) when a new page is requested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222252/how-to-use-angularjs-routes-with-express-node-js-when-a-new-page-is-requested)