# How to do serverside HTML5 mode URL Rewriting with NodeJS and browserSync

Tags: angularjs, node.js, browser-sync

#### How to remove #! getting added to url in my AngularJS application?

I have tried:-  `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');` and adding  `<base href="/">` but to no avail. When I navigate to a particular url, #! disappears but when I tried to reload, it gives the error:- `Cannot GET`.

So I looked online, and found out that doing above is only half of the solution. We also need to rewrite the logic on server side as well. So I am using NodeJS and browserSync package to fire up localhost. So what is the solutioin to this?

Note:- My backend and frontend code are separate and both handle routing.

Comment: If you are using express you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31778453/8574934) answer. Add the snippet right before you start listening.

Comment: @MikaS Where to put it?

Comment: Right above `app.listen()` for example.

Comment: My backend and frontend code are separate and both handle routing. @MikaS

Comment: Isn't the backend still serving index.html when the app loads?

Answer (score 0):

There is a option in Browsersync called **single** which serves the index.html as a fallback if the url does not exist.

> Serve an index.html file for all non-asset routes. Useful when using client-routers

See documentation:
https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-single

```
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: 'dist',        
    },
    single: true
});
```